# javascript merge arrays into a single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am trying to merge several arrays into a single object that I can then iterate to use in chart.js datasets. I have a set of data that looks like this:

```
export const data = [
    {
        'name': 'Flow',
        'values': {
            'sent': 410,
            'responded': 253,
            'secured': 65
        }
    }
]
```

(I limited this to just one, but the dataset is much larger)

Then I have several arrays that I've built based on this data:

```
this.labels = data.map(item => item.name);
this.colors = ['#439ff4', '#5ec3d5', '#a068e5'];
this.responded = data.map(item => item.values.responded);
this.sent = data.map(item => item.values.sent);
this.secured = data.map(item => item.values.secured);
```

What I need to do is this:

1. get the key names (responded, sent, secured) as another array
2. merge the keys, colors, responded, sent, and secured, arrays into an object called datasets.

   `this.datasets = [ /* not sure what to do here! */];`

Ultimately my chart in chart js is looking for something like this (I have partially hard-coded values at the moment:

```
datasets: [
    {
        label: 'Sent',
        data: this.sent,
        backgroundColor: '#439ff4'
    },
    {
        label: 'Responded',
        data: this.responded,
        backgroundColor: '#5ec3d5'
    },
    {
        label: 'Secured',
        data: this.secured,
        backgroundColor: '#a068e5'
    }
],
```

that I would ultimately like to just express as

`datasets: this.datasets,`

I hope I explained this well enough as to what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the key names in `data.values` stays in lowercase and otherwise it is same as `datasets[*].label`, you can do something like below.

```js
// the custom type is just for making it more manageable, omit it if you want
type DatasetItem = { label: string, data: number[], backgroundColor: string };

let datasets: Array<Partial<DatasetItem>> = [
    {
        label: 'Sent',
        backgroundColor: '#439ff4'
    },
    {
        label: 'Responded',
        backgroundColor: '#5ec3d5'
    },
    {
        label: 'Secured',
        backgroundColor: '#a068e5'
    }
];    

const data = [
    {
        'name': 'Flow1',
        'values': {
            'sent': 410,
            'responded': 253,
            'secured': 65
        }
    },
    {
        'name': 'Flow2',
        'values': {
            'sent': 411,
            'responded': 254,
            'secured': 66
        }
    }
];

datasets.forEach((item) => item.data = data.map((d) => d.values[item.label.toLowerCase()]));    
console.log(datasets);
```